# <Method 'Range of object' _Global' failed> - Still getting error when specifying worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting this VBA error even though I am referencing the worksheet that I am using in the code. I don't use VBA very often so this may be an easy question.

```
Sub ParseJSON()
    Dim jsonText As String
    Dim jsonObj As Dictionary
    Dim jsonRows As Collection
    Dim jsonRow As Collection
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim currentRow As Long
    Dim startColumn As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'Create a real JSON object
    jsonText = ws.Range("B2").Value

    'Parse it
    Set jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonText)

    'Set the starting row where to put the values
    currentRow = 5

    'First column where to put the values
    startColumn = 1 'A

    'For i = 1 To jsonObj.Count
     'ws.Cells(currentRow, startColumn) = jsonObj
    'Next i


    For Each strKey In jsonObj.keys()
    With ws
     Range("A", strKey) = jsonObj(strKey)
    End With
    Next

        'ws.Range("A", strKey).Activate = jsonObj(strKey)

    'Get the rows collection
    'agencyID = jsonObj("agencyID")
    'agencyName = jsonObj("agencyName")


    'Set the starting row where to put the values
    currentRow = 1

    'First column where to put the values
    startColumn = 2 'B

    'Loop through all the values received
    'For Each jsonRow In jsonRows
        'Now loop through all the items in this row
        'For i = 1 To jsonRow.Count
            ws.Cells(5, 5) = agencyID
        'Next i

        'Increment the row to the next one
        'currentRow = currentRow + 1
    'Next jsonRow
End Sub
```

**I get the error on this line**

```
With ws
     Range("A", strKey) = jsonObj(strKey)
    End With
```

Method 'Range of object' _Global' failed

[image: Screenshot]

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: What does the value `strKey` contain? I see wrong with the line `Range("A", strKey) = jsonObj(strKey)`. Also, you will have to make it `.Range("A" & colNumber) = jsonObj(strKey)`

Comment: @shahkalpesh See screenshot. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: The code in the image is different than what you have posted here. I will post the code below. Please check and let me know if you face any error.

Comment: try `.Range("A" & strKey) = jsonObj(strKey)`

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each strKey In jsonObj.keys()
   ws.Cells(currentRow, startColumn).Value = jsonObj(strKey)
   currentRow = currentRow + 1
Next
```

EDIT: The error occurs in your case, because the key could be `agencyID` - which will result in the following code

`Range("A", "agencyID") = "valueOfAgencyID"`

Excel won't be able to find a cell with address/name `AagencyID`, hence the error.